# Checkedlistbox refresh not working

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have this method to open and fill checkedlistbox.

```
 void Show_files()
    {

            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath);
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(FBD.SelectedPath);

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(file);
                }
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dir);
                }
            }
        }
```

and then button to delete selected files.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList())
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Czy na pewno chcesz usunać zaznaczone pliki", "Czy na pewno chcesz usunać zaznaczone pliki?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                File.Delete(item); 
            }
          }
        MessageBox.Show("Usunięto");
        checkedListBox1.Refresh();  // here should refresh list of folder content
    }
```

I've tried to clear and add items again in loop (if items count not null) in method Show_files() but it hasn't worked. Hide and show neither. I don't want to open folder browser again. It has to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't removing the item from the control:

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
  File.Delete(item);
  checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Best to put some Try...Catch blocks around such operations.

Comment: can't modify the items inside the foreach loop